# Filling View while timer is counting

Tags: android, listview, timer

I am using a horizontal list in android where each view represents an order.
As soon as a view is touched a timer starts counting. 
While the timer is counting this view is filled with a color and when the timer stops the view is completely filled.

this is an example on how it should look like, the view is filled with a blue color while timer is ticking:

[image]

Any suggestions or knowledge of libraries?

Answer (score 0):

A quite straight forward way would be to create a custom view which draws the blue color from the bottom to top, where the top variable varies in regards to how much time has passed in the timer.

You can read more about custom views and how to create one here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html